# A rectangle is a countable union of rectangles $\rightarrow$ It's area is at most the sum of the areas

Tags: geometry, rectangles

Let $R \in \mathbb{R}^2 $ be a closed rectangle (i.e, a set of the form $[a, b]\times [c, d]$). Its area is defined by $S(R)=(b-a)(d-c)$.

Now, suppose $R=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}R_i$ when $R_i$ are also rectangles.
I need to prove that $S(R)\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}S(R_i)$.
Note that no measure theory is allowed, only "basic" tools.

It's quite harder than I expected. Any suggestions?

Comment: Very nice question!

Comment: It's easy to solve using compacts, or measure theory , but it's actually more pretty to solve using only basic tools!

Comment: What level of math is this?  Do you know anything about compact sets?  Anything about measure theory?

Comment: I know  a lot about compact sets and measure theory.
Using compactness is allowed, measure theory isn't.
Edit: just noticed Heine-Borel is a direction. I'll think about it

Comment: First of all. Let's prove this for $[0,1] \times [0,1]$. Because of I could get bijection between this rectangular and others.
Actually Heine-Borell lemme give us very important thing, because of $R$ compact there is finite sequence of rectangular from **any set of rectangulars which cover R**. So let's assume that $ 1 = S(R) > \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} S(R_{i})$, this should be true always. So we should find appropriate sequence of rectangulars which give us contradiction.

Comment: But using norms this is obvious to show using triangle-inequality